# DataContract on entities from Entity Framework Code-First class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

I'm using the **EF6** code-first for building a database, which I need for a **WCF Service**. My DbSet would be something like:

```
 public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Town { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to get the customer's data with a get-method from my **WCF service**.
I came up with the idea to have the whole class as a *[DataContract]* with each property as a *[DataMember]*.

So far there should be no problem and I checked online if there is any recommendation or 'best practice' in this scenario. So I found [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444221/5922315) in that **Pein** is saying:

> First of all you should **never** expose the whole entity as a data contract, as it is a domain object, not the data transfer object.

So my question is: why shouldn't one have the entity as data contract? And if so, is it a better way to have different classes with data contract for receiving and sending my data from the entities?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can have some sort of validation before filling your entities, its just in case you don't leak or receive unwanted data.

Comment: yes, I do have a validation. And I'm using a custom UserNamePasswordValidationMode. So I only want to have users with the right credentials receiving the data.

Comment: That user is right that you are putting the burdens of two very different  concerns on one class here. You will get away with it in a small project but otherwise separate DTO classes are recommended. This question may be  better suited for the CodeReview site.

Comment: @HenkHolterman The only way this is suitable on Code Review is if the OP includes the entire object, and all related code so that we may better comment on the entire aspect. Furthermore, doing so does not guarantee that any reviewers **will** comment on the design / why not to use the same object for DB and DTO, I feel like, once fleshed out properly, this would better fit [SoftwareEngineering.SE].